# Custom Calculator get the last selected operation with a new value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a test calculator and i managed to get some functionalities working like Add, Multiply.
For the last part i need a way to get an Apply functionality that will **perform the last operation with the newly selected number.**

Examples of the calculator lifecycles

[image]

Here is a [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/muscaiu/k14vvbdf/4/)

Any ideas? Thank you!

**HTML**

```
    <select ng-model="selectedOperation">
        <option value="Add">Add</option>
        <option value="Multiply">Multiply</option>
        <option value="Apply">Apply</option>
    </select>
    <input ng-model="selectedNumber" />
    <button ng-click="addItem()
```

**JS**

```
.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.addItem = function(){
        $scope.items.push({
            myOperation: $scope.selectedOperation,
            myNumber: $scope.selectedNumber 
        });

        $scope.selectedOperation = '';
        $scope.selectedNumber = '';
    }

    $scope.AddToTotal = function(){
        var total = 0;

        for(var i=0; i<$scope.items.length; i++){
            if($scope.items[i].myOperation ==="Add"){
                total += $scope.items[i].myNumber;
            }
            if($scope.items[i].myOperation ==="Multiply"){
                total *= $scope.items[i].myNumber;
            }
            if($scope.items[i].myOperation ==="Apply"){
                ??????????????
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you describe what the `Apply` method will actually do with the number? The first example does not make much sense to me, because the order seems incorrect. How can `add 2; multiply 3; apply 3` evaluate to this order `(3 + 2) * 3`? Shouldn't that be `(3 * 2) + 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand that example right, what you need is not performing the last operation with the newly selected number, but performing all the steps with the newly selected number. If so, then you have to create such variable `startValue` and update it when step with `Apply` value occurs.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.startValue = 0;

        $scope.addItem = function(){
                if($scope.selectedOperation === 'Apply'){
                $scope.startValue = $scope.selectedNumber;
            }
            $scope.items.push({
                myOperation: $scope.selectedOperation,
                myNumber: $scope.selectedNumber 
            });

            $scope.selectedOperation = '';
            $scope.selectedNumber = '';
        }

        $scope.AddToTotal = function(){
            var total = $scope.startValue;

            for(var i=0; i<$scope.items.length; i++){
                if($scope.items[i].myOperation ==="Add"){
                    total += $scope.items[i].myNumber;
                }
                if($scope.items[i].myOperation ==="Multiply"){
                    total *= $scope.items[i].myNumber;
                }
                //if($scope.items[i].myOperation ==="Apply"){
                //    total = $scope.items[i].myNumber;
                //}
                //uita-te in array in ultimul item
            }
            return total;
        }

        $scope.resetItems = function(){
            console.log('reset')
            $scope.items.length = 0;
            $scope.startValue = 0;
        }
    })
```

And Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/75xz5qvf/1/

Let me know if I'm right : )

Comment: At first i thought you are wrong, but now I think you understood this better then i did, and i read it 50 times, holy hell!!  I don't know how you made it work, yet. I will try implement it and let you know soon!

Comment: Yes your answer is correct. But now i have a bigger problem. I can't use angular. I can only use jQuery or Vanilla ..oh boy :( ..You have any tips on how to get started with this? Thank for the answer again!

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.result;

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.items.push({
      myOperation: $scope.selectedOperation,
      myNumber: parseInt($scope.selectedNumber)
    });
    $scope.selectedOperation = '';
    $scope.selectedNumber = '';
  }

  $scope.AddToTotal = function() {
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.items[i].myOperation === "Add") {
        total = (total == 0 ? $scope.items[i].myNumber + $scope.items[i + 1].myNumber :
          total + $scope.items[i + 1].myNumber);
      } else if ($scope.items[i].myOperation === "Multiply") {
        total = (total == 0 ? $scope.items[i].myNumber * $scope.items[i + 1].myNumber :
          total * $scope.items[i + 1].myNumber);
      } else {
        $scope.result = (total == 0 ? $scope.items[i].myNumber : total);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <select ng-model="selectedOperation">
    <option value="Add">Add</option>
    <option value="Multiply">Multiply</option>
    <option value="Apply">Apply</option>
  </select>
  <input ng-model="selectedNumber" />
  <button ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
  <button ng-click="AddToTotal()">AddToTotal</button>
  </br>
  </br>result: {{result}}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You Demo doesn't seem to work and i don't see any `Apply` function, but it is interesting. Can you translate this please?: `total = (total == 0 ? $scope.items[i].myNumber + $scope.items[i + 1].myNumber :
          total + $scope.items[i + 1].myNumber);`

Comment: this is equal to: if(total==0){ total=$scope.items[i].myNumber + $scope.items[i + 1].myNumber } else

Comment: this is equal to:                                                                               if(total==0){ total=$scope.items[i].myNumber + $scope.items[i+1].myNumber }                                                                                     else { total = total + $scope.items[i + 1].myNumber);}

Comment: if you run code for your example in top you will see answer.